# Count, empty? fails for ActiveRecord with outer joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models, `Monkey` and `Session`, where `Monkey` `has_many` `Session`. I have a scope for `Monkey`:

```
scope :with_session_counts, -> {
    joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN `sessions` ON `sessions`.`monkey_id` = `monkeys`.`id`")
    .group(:id)
    .select("`monkeys`.*, COUNT(DISTINCT `sessions`.`id`) as session_count")
}
```

in order to grab the number of associated `Session`s (even when 0).

Querying `@monkeys = Monkey.with_session_counts` works as expected. However, when I test in my view:

```
<% unless @monkeys.empty?%>
```

I get this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous:
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count_all, id AS id FROM `monkeys`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `sessions` ON `sessions`.`monkey_id` = `monkeys`.`id`
GROUP BY `monkeys`.`id`
```

How would I convince Rails to prefix `id` with the table name in presence of the `JOIN`?
Or is there a better alternative for the `OUTER JOIN`?

This applies equally to calling `@monkeys.count(:all)`. I'm using RoR 4.2.1.

**Update:**

I have a partial fix for my issue (specify `group("monkeys.id")` explicitly) I wonder whether this is a bug in the code that generates the `SELECT` clause for `count(:all)`. Note that in both cases (`group("monkeys.id")` and `group(:id)`) the `GROUP BY` part is generated correctly (i.e. with `monkeys.id`), but in the latter case the `SELECT` only contains `id AS id`. The reason I say 'partial' is because it works in that it does not break a call to `empty?`, but a call to `count(:all)` returns a Hash `{monkey_id => number_of_sessions}` instead of the number of records.

**Update 2:**
I guess my real question is: How can I get the number of associated sessions for each monkey, so that for all intents and purposes I can work with the query result as with `Monkey.all`?  I know about counter cache but would prefer not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not a bug. Like you added on your update, you have to specify the table that the `id` column belongs to. In this case `group('monkeys.id')` would do it.

How would the code responsible for generating the statement know the table to use? Without the `count` worked fine because it adds `points.*` to the projection and that is the one used by `group by`. However, if you actually wanted to `group by` Sessions `id`, you would have to specify it anyway.

Comment: But for the `GROUP BY` part the table is inferred correctly when `group(:id)` is given?

Comment: Yes for the first query since you have ``monkeys`.*`. The second one with the `count` will add the column that you want to `group by` to the projection, leaving the statement ambiguous. That's why you need to clarify your `group by` column.